# Pass Table Values into Variables

Tags: sql, t-sql, variables, datatables

I have a table with Names and some values.  I want to pass the values associated to the names into another table to prepopulate a list of values.  I'm not sure the best way to approach this either by creating a function or procedure.

Below is the query I have now where I have to SET the variables manually.  But rather doing it manually I would like to pass the values from the other table into this.  How would I do this?

Example I have a table called ABC and in that table 3 values

```
Name|AVG |DEV
A   |1.89|.74
B   |2.43|1.20
C   |.74 |.12
```

I want to pass the all the values from that table in the query below.  The AVG value in the table into the @AVG variable in the below query and the DEV value in the table into the @deviation table below.

The results can be put into a new table or in a query.

```
DECLARE @avg DECIMAL(4,1) = 1.89 --this would be row 1 (value A) avg
DECLARE @deviation DECIMAL(4,1) = 0.74 --this would be row 1 (value A) DEV


DECLARE @startnum DECIMAL(4,1)= @Avg - (@deviation * 3)
DECLARE @endnum DECIMAL(4,1)= @Avg + (@deviation * 3)



;
WITH gen AS (
    SELECT CAST(@startnum AS decimal(4,1)) AS Mulitiple
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(Mulitiple+.1 AS decimal(4,1)) FROM gen WHERE Mulitiple+.1<=@endnum
)
SELECT A.Mulitiple , CAST(((A.Mulitiple-@avg)/@deviation) AS DECImAL(4,2)) AS  ZScore
,Z.Y AS Area
FROM gen AS A
LEFT JOIN STAT..ZScore AS Z ON CAST(((A.Mulitiple-@avg)/@deviation) AS DECImAL(4,2)) = CAST(Z.Zscore AS decimal(4,2))
--WHERE Z.Y IS NOT NULL 
option (maxrecursion 10000)
```

Comment: I'm a little lost.  The table has *three* rows with three "average" values.  What do you want in the variable?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Instead of a recursive CTE the rows could be generated more efficiently using a "numbers function" or [tally function](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1) and the query could be simpler

Comment: The startnum/endnum calculation are used to generate a range of numbers incremented by 0.1 and the number of rows to generate is 2*dev*3, or 6*deviation?

Comment: I want to pass the first rows average and DEV into the DECLARE avg in the query and the DECLARE deviation in the query below.  Then insert the results from the query below into a table then process the second rows average and DEV into the same thing and insert those results into the table, repeating till it goes through all the records in the ABC table.  Basically want to loop though the values in the ABC table and pass them though the variables in the query.

Comment: @SteveC yes exactly.  The range of numbers will be different based on the avg and dev I pass to it.  Its basically giving me points where I can plot the data on the bell curve and identifying the area

Comment: @JustinStaugaitis gotcha.  The tally function is cross applied so the input parameters vary by each row of abc.  It acts like a loop and generates the zscores.  The answer code should do what you're looking for

Comment: Sorry I wrote the comment incompletely.  The tally function doesn't directly generate zscores.  It generates a sequence of numbers as rows (fn.N) and then gets used to calculate the zscores

Comment: @SteveC that worked beautifully, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach uses a [tally function](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1) named dbo.fnNumbers to generate the range of zscores.

dbo.fnNumbers

```
create function [dbo].[fnNumbers](
  @zero_or_one   bit, 
  @n             bigint)
returns table with schemabinding as return
with n(n) as (select null from (values (1),(2),(3),(4)) n(n))
select 0 n where @zero_or_one = 0
union all
select top(@n) row_number() over(order by (select null)) n
from n na, n nb, n nc, n nd, n ne, n nf, n ng, n nh,
     n ni, n nj, n nk, n nl, n nm, n np, n nq, n nr;
```

Query

```
drop table if exists #abc;
go
create table #abc(
   [name]   varchar(2),
   [avg]    decimal(4,1),
   [dev]    decimal(4,1));

insert #abc([name], [avg], [dev]) values
('a', 1.89,  .74),
('b', 2.43, 1.20),
('c', 0.74,  .12);

select a.[name], gen.multiple, gen_z.zscore, z.y as area
from #abc a
     cross apply dbo.fnNumbers(1, cast(2*(a.dev*3)+0.1 as decimal(4,1))*10) fn
     cross apply (values (cast((a.[avg]-(a.dev*3)+(fn.N-1)*0.1) as decimal(4,1)))) gen(multiple)
     cross apply (values (cast(((gen.multiple-a.[avg])/a.dev) AS decimal(4,2)))) gen_z(zscore)
     left join stat..zscore z on gen_z.zscore=cast(z.zscore as decimal(4,2))
order by a.[name], gen.multiple;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can just use `JOIN`.  In this case, you can introduce the table using `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT ABC.*, A.Mulitiple ,
       CAST(((A.Mulitiple - ABC.avg) / ABC.dev) AS DECImAL(4, 2)) AS  ZScore
,Z.Y AS Area
FROM ABC CROSS JOIN
     gen a LEFT JOIN
     STAT..ZScore Z
     ON CAST(((A.Mulitiple - abc.avg)/ abc.dev) AS DECIMAL(4,2)) = CAST(Z.Zscore AS decimal(4,2))
--WHERE Z.Y IS NOT NULL
```

You can avoid having the formula twice by using:

```
SELECT ABC.*, A.Mulitiple, v.ZScore, Z.Y AS Area
FROM ABC CROSS JOIN
     gen a CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CAST((A.Mulitiple - ABC.avg) / ABC.dev AS DECImAL(4, 2))
     ) v(Zscore) LEFT JOIN
     STAT..ZScore Z
     ON v.ZScore = CAST(Z.Zscore AS decimal(4,2))
--WHERE Z.Y IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: The query below generates numbers so I can plot points.  Those numbers from the below query are based on avg and dev from the first row in the ABC, the second row avg and DEV will have completely different results from the query.  So the number of rows from the below query will be different everytime.